# Get the index of the nth occurrence of an element in a Rust Vector

Tags: rust

I would like a function to get the index of the nth occurrence of an element. It would have a function signature like so:

`fn get_index(vec, occurence, value)`

For example, to get the index of the second occurence of the element 1 in a given vector:

```
let v: Vec<u8> = vec![3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1];

assert_eq!(get_index(v, 2, 1), 5)
```

Comment: It is unclear what you tried, and what specifically you are struggling with. You need to `iter()`ate over the vector, `enumerate()` it, `filter()` it and then take the `nth()` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function might look something like:

```rust
fn get_index(v: Vec<u8>, occurrence: usize, value: u8) -> Option<usize> {
    v.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .filter(|(_, &v)| v == value)
        .map(|(i, _)| i)
        .nth(occurrence - 1)
}
```

Explaining this process:

1. We take an iterator of our Vector `v`.
2. We `enumerate` this iterator, transforming it into [(0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), ...]. This way, we can preserve the index of the item after filtering.
3. We filter our enumeration based on whether the value (the right hand item in the tuple) is equal to the element we're looking for.
4. We map and remove the value part as it is no longer relevant (but keeping the index) .
5. We take the `occurrence`nth item, which is an Option that may contain the index (because it may not exist).

```rust
#[test]
fn given() {
    assert_eq!(get_index(vec![3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1], 2, 1), Some(5));
}
```

Note that the function should return an Option (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/), because we can't be certain that `v` will contain as many occurrences of the value as you have specified.

Comment: This allocates a `Vec` for no reason. You can just use `nth()`.

Comment: Hadn't used that before, nice spot. Edited.